# Try to move a slice to another with GpuDevice but got `error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘const struct Eigen::GpuDevice’`

Tags: c++, tensorflow, eigen

I was writing an op for Tensorflow in C++, in the middle of codes I try to move an slice of input to an same slice of output, with a certain device. But it ends up with an error like `/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorMorphing.h:401:11: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘const struct Eigen::GpuDevice’`.

I believe some other operations also have assignment to a tensor's slice (such as concat_op), but still could not figure out where my code differs from theirs (I am rather new to C++, so maybe it is a dumb question).

The code fragment is the following:

```
// definition of i, h, w, c, both `input_` and `output_` are `TTypes<T,4>::Tensor`
// aka `Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 4, 1, long int>`
const Device& d = context->eigen_device<Device>();
auto start = Eigen::array<int, 4>{i, 0, 0, 0};
auto size = Eigen::array<int, 4>{1, h, w, c};            
auto output_slice = output_.slice(start, size);
output_slice.device(d) = input_.slice(start, size);
```

whole error message like:

```
/home/antonio/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorMorphing.h:401:11:
 error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘const struct Eigen::GpuDevice’
       m_device.memcpy((void*)(data+i), src+offset, contiguous_values * sizeof(Scalar));
```

Comment: You are likely missing the header which defines `Eigen::GpuDevice`..

Comment: @François Andrieux This is exactly what baffles me, if I miss a header in current file, then it should report as error when I define `const Device &d` rather than the last line, if I'm missing a header in other files... well they all belongs to Eigen or Tensorflow.

Comment: There is likely a [forward declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Forward_declaration) for `Eigen:GpuDevice` in one of the headers you are using. So any pointer or reference to a device will compile fun, but any attempt to actually use them will fail.